# Check for Firebase Dynamic Links configuration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

While validating my dynamic link configuration from the link

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.page.link/apple-app-site-association
```

I am getting the reponse as

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /_/*",
          "/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Whereas the blog https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive has defined a configured dynamic link as

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "1234567890.com.example.ios",
        "paths": [
          "/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where `paths` doesn't contain `NOT`.

Can it be the reason my dynamic link is showing 'Invalid Dynamic link' on clicking from Sign-in link received in the email?

Answer (score 1):

> Can it be the reason my dynamic link is showing 'Invalid Dynamic link' on clicking from Sign-in link received in the email?

No. Their documentation just seems to be outdated. All Dynamic Link domains will have these two items in the `paths` key, just tested with a few of my own domains.

This is unless your Dynamic Link is of the form `domain.page.link/_/something`, in which case the `apple-app-site-association` explicitly prohibits the OS to open the URL in the app. But I doubt that your URL is of that format.

Hence, your issue is somewhere else, I'm afraid. I'd suggest that you double check the team ID and bundle ID if they really match with the app you expect to get opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cross checked my bundle Id as well as Team Id. For me Team Id was totally different from my AppId Prefix so I selected App Id prefix from the profile i am using. Could you please have a look to my Invalid Dynamic link issue with more description. I think you might guess the problem from that description. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647529/i-am-getting-invalid-dynamic-link-when-clicking-to-the-sign-in-link-received-thr)

Comment: Hello @fphilipe, I am also getting this NOT in associated links and also double-checked the bundle id as well as team id. so now what could be the problem?