# I am getting Invalid Dynamic Link when clicking to the Sign-in link received through email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am getting Invalid Dynamic Link when clicking to the Sign-in link received through email. [image: screen shot of the error]

```
   actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://caxxxxxxxxxxxant.page.link") //my domain prefix
   actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
   actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
```

- But when I provide the url as :

```
actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://caxxxxxxxxxant.page.link/open")
```

with custom url scheme i gave while making Dynamic Link under the domain, it's now navigating me to my app with error 'error in sign-in' by going else part of the below code. *

```
 if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link) {
            guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Email") as? String else {
                print("Error signing in: email does not exist")
                return true
            }
        }
    else{
        print("error in sign-in")
        }
        return false
}
```

The link I am getting while receiving the dynamic link in app delegate restorationHandler: method is

```
<https://caxxxxxxxxxxxxant.page.link/?link=https://sxxxx-axxxxt-exxa.firebaseapp.com&isi=14xxxxxx8&ibi=com.cxxxxxr.sxxxxxt&st=Eagle+Eye+Sales+Assistant+App&sd=Now+you+can+get+all+the+Eagle+Eye+documents+and+information+within+a+fingerprint.&cid=5xxxx60xxx558&_osl=https://caxxxxxxxxant.page.link/open&_fpb=CJxxxxxHQg==&_cpt=cpit&_iumenbl=1&_iumchkactval=1&_plt=895&_uit=1062&_cpb=1>
```

I guess this is because my incoming link doesn't contain email with it.

Please help me, how can I get my link authenticated in Auth.auth().isSignIn(withemailLink : Link) method. How can I get the link with email.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Firebase Auth doesn't support custom FDL domains with paths.
Second, if you want to use a custom FDL domain, you need to set `actionCodeSettings.url` to a fallback URL in case the user clicks the link on a different device (where the iOS app is not installed). You will need to set the FDL domain `caxxxxxxxxxxxant.page.link` in `actionCodeSettings.dynamicLinkDomain`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You are right. Now the url : `actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://caxxxxxxxxxxxant.page.link")` is navigating me to my app, but if my app is not in the device its again showing me Invalid Dynamic Link error. Could you please help me, how can I open it in app-store when app is not installed. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what is going on. If the app is not installed, it should redirect to the web fallback URL. Can you provide a sample of the URL that is showing that error?

Comment: How can I provide fallback url so that at least it should show some page instead of Invalid dynamic link error. I am still trying to show app store if the app is not installed. But didn't get luck for any two of them.

Comment: Did you set a custom FDL link as your action callback URL in the Firebase Console? I think that may be the cause of the issue.