# Customize Invalid Dynamic Link Page

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to serve a custom Invalid Dynamic Link page which catches all invalid dynamic links. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you try this answer on a different post to see if it works? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658806/5131363

Comment: This post was not what I was looking for I am trying to make sure that my customers get redirected to a custom link instead of getting the error page.